# How to change gcc compile message in makefile

Tags: compilation, makefile, message

I am new to programming.

I need to help me with hiding a message in makefile.
Let me show you:

When compiling this set of files(grid.cc attribute.cc targa.cc) http://prntscr.com/67ack4

I see this message:  gcc5 -Wall -O2 -pipe -mtune=i686 -c attribute.cc

And I want to defend me something like: Compilation targa.cc
And I want to defend me something like: Compilation attribute.cc
etc 
etc ...

I hope you understand what I mean.

Here is my makefile :

```html
BIN = ../libgame.a


CXX = gcc5
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -pipe -mtune=i686

OBJFILES = grid.o attribute.o targa.o

########################################################################################################

default:
 $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c grid.cc
 $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c attribute.cc
 $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c targa.cc
 ar cru $(BIN) $(OBJFILES)
 ranlib $(BIN)
 rm -f *.o
```

Comment: Yes, but i dont't understand

Comment: Stick `@echo 'Compiling $@';` at the start of each of those lines. Or use [this](https://gist.github.com/deryni/017dc953c75b9396b80d) and add `$(GEN)` or add your own compiling silent rule and use that.

Comment: Etan Reisner Thanks , you answer is correct. It works. Have a nice day :D

Comment: Why are you even using make here?  You're basically just writing a shell script in a makefile, by putting all the commands in a single rule.  This is useless; if you want the same set of commands to be run every time, just write a shell script directly.  It'll be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an automake-style silent rules trick to control what is output for your commands.

To do this directly you would do this:

```
BIN = ../libgame.a

CXX = gcc5
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -pipe -mtune=i686

OBJFILES = grid.o attribute.o targa.o
########################################################################################################

default:
    @echo 'Compiling grid.cc';$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c grid.cc
    @echo 'Compiling attribute.cc';$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c attribute.cc
    @echo 'Compiling targa.cc';$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c targa.cc
    ar cru $(BIN) $(OBJFILES)
    ranlib $(BIN)
    rm -f *.o
```

Alternatively you could use my [`silent_rules.mk`](https://gist.github.com/deryni/017dc953c75b9396b80d) and use:

```
 $(eval $(call vrule,Compile,Compiling $$(value 1))

 $(call Compile,grid.cc);$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c grid.cc
 $(call Compile,attribute.cc);$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c attribute.cc
 $(call Compile,targa.cc);$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c targa.cc
```

to get `Compiling grid.cc`, `Compiling attribute.cc` and `Compiling targa.cc` messages instead. (If you were using proper targets for your object files you could use the default `$(GEN)` silent rule to get `GEN xxx.o` output automatically.